# using grok pattern to skip a part from mesage

Tags: logstash-grok

how can we get just extract the sessionid number from a pattern in grok 
for example
`"sessionid$:999"`

I am trying to use `%{DATA:line}` but it gets

```
  "line": [
    [
      " Sessionid$:999"
    ]
```

how can  just get the session number and ignore `"sessionId$"` in it

Thanks

Comment: ok i got it working it with  ".*SessionId.\s*:%{BASE10NUM:line}"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**GROK pattern:**

```
Sessionid.\s*:%{NUMBER:line}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
  "line": [
    [
      "999"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "999"
    ]
  ]
}
```